# unable to launch WindowsXp image on openstack

Tags: openstack

I tried openstack on my laptop, my setup is like this

Host Machine: Windows 7
Virtualisation: VirtualBox

Ubuntu12 is running on this VirtualBox, On this Ubuntu12, I installed OpenStack Essex packages with qemu as hypervisor, and added few uec linux images on to glance, I was able to access linux images using ssh and vnc, it was great success.

Now, It has become very challenging to upload Windows image , it was really a night mare I tried all possible ways, searched in google found lot of solutions, but nothing worked, at last I converted WindowsXp.vdi file to WindowsXp.img using VBoxManage and added to glance, once I launch it I am getting blue screen error and windowsxp is horribly
restarting......................... So please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Your windows images (server or desktop) will BSOD without the correct drivers for the virtualization that you have chosen. Try installing the windows image with one of the drivers at http://www.claunia.com/qemu/drivers/index.html (QEMU drivers) and see how it goes.

***Please note**: Windows is notoriously difficult to run on **any** cloud not just OpenStack. In addition to the drivers, you will wrestle with image format (like you have) and initialization problems (otherwise all the images come up with that same GUIDs).*